# How to create bean edit model for complex type in Tapestry

Tags: java, list, tapestry

I have two objects:

```
Person {
    private integer id;
    private string name;
    private EnumPersonType personType:
    //constructors, getters and setters
}

Description {
    private integer id;
    private string descriptionText;
    private List<Person> creators; // hibernate manyToMany with joinTable
    // constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Now, in T5:
1. I create few Persons (CreatePersonPage.java/.tml) - WORKING OK
2. I need to create Description and select few person to put into Description.creators list in `<beaneditor t:object="description".../>`. I got *Bean Editor Model for Description does not contain property named 'creators'* exception.
What I need to do to step by step have this UseCase working with Tapestry? Please note that this is List of Persons as property.

Comment: Has anyone found out how to write BeanModel blocks for Types containing more than one field?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few decisions you need to make:

1. Will this all be done on a single page? Or multiple pages?
2. Will this be done via ajax updates? Or full page refreshes?
3. Will I need to hold onto temp changes before the "save" button is clicked? Where will these temp changes be stored? (clientside, serverside session, serverside database)

You'll probably be interested in looking at the [Loop](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Loop.html) component and also the [AjaxFormLoop](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/AjaxFormLoop.html) component.

Jumpstart has many CRUD examples [here](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/)

You might be interested in the [Ajax Filter CRUD](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/together/ajaxfiltercrud/persons) example

Comment: None of the example you linked to, shows how to use complex types in a **bean edit model**. The only example on *jumpstart* handles only a very simple and flat bean. No Lists, no Types containing more than one field, ...